# Is there any way I can trigger send/enter key automatically?

Tags: android

I tried this, but it did not work

```
Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
```

Comment: To your own app, or another?  You can do it to your own app, but not to a random app (such as whatever app has focus).

Comment: I need to do it on another app

Comment: Then no.  There is no way

Comment: but keyboard is my default ..So why it is not possible ?

Comment: If you're building a keyboard app, and the keyboard is currently showing, you can send events via the InputConnection returned from inputMethodSerice.getInputConnection().  But if you aren't on screen or you aren't a keyboard there's no way.

Comment: I have entered to the third party app and inserted into edit text now I only need to send the text on click  programmatically